# tabularx and new environments

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx, documentclass-writing

so I am writing my own LaTex class so that I can use it to automatically generate invoices with information provided from the user. As such, I have encountered an issue with tabularx and new environments and I am looking for a way around the issue that it presents. If one defines a new environment as such:

```
\newenvironment{test}[1]
{
    #1\\
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
}
{
    \end{tabularx}
}
```

The parser complains about reading past EOF or something similar, however; if I were to use `tabular` or `tabular*` the parser allows this, and one is allowed to add entries to the table as normal. Is there a way around this, if not, is there a way to get a dynamic column that can fill up a size so that the table takes up for example `\textwidth` amount of horizontal space?

Comment: see the tabularx documentation, you need to use `\tabularx` not `\begin{tabularx}` but I can't think of any cases when you would want `\\ ` before a table?

Comment: I mean.. the \\ is just there so that it doesn't seem like I am just making an environment of an existing environment

Comment: I wouldn't use tabularx for such invoices. It doesn't allow pagebreaks.

Answer (score 3):

As it states in the package documentation, you need the `\tabularx` form in an environment definition.

```
\newenvironment{test}[1]
{%%
    #1%%

    \noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{X r}%%
}
{%%
    \endtabularx
}
```